# PyQt5 не работает переход из окна в другое окно

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Программа планируется большой, поэтому я решила разделить ее на несколько логический файлов с интерфейсами окон. 
Проблема возникает на этапе перехода из второго окна в третье (с первым переходом мне помогли).

(Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)).

1 файл **Welcome_Screen.py** (переход кнопкой cust_btn)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication

from Customer_screen import CustomerScreen


class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi('screens/welcomescreen.ui', self)

        self.cust_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_to_CustomerData)

    def go_to_CustomerData(self):
        client = CustomerScreen(widget)  # +++ (widget)
        widget.addWidget(client)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)


# main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))
    app.setApplicationDisplayName('Bonus Program')
    welcome = WelcomeScreen()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(welcome)
    widget.setFixedWidth(600)
    widget.setFixedHeight(475)
    widget.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except:
        print("Exiting")
```

2 файл **Customer_Screen.py** (переход кнопкой soldto_btn)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from Soldto_screen import SoldtoScreen

class CustomerScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super(CustomerScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("screens/customerscreen.ui", self)

        self.widget = widget  # +++

        self.back_btn.setIcon(QIcon('Icons/Back.png'))
        self.back_btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 60))
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_Back_to_WelcomeScreen)
        self.soldto_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_to_Soldto_list)

    def go_Back_to_WelcomeScreen(self):
        self.widget.setCurrentIndex(0)


    def go_to_Soldto_list(self):
        soldto = SoldtoScreen(widget)  # +++ (widget)
        widget.addWidget(soldto)
        widget.widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)
```

3 файл **Soldto_screen.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SoldtoScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, widget):  # +++ widget
        super(SoldtoScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("screens/soldtoscreen.ui", self)

        self.st_widget = widget  # +++

        self.back_btn.setIcon(QIcon('Icons/Back.png'))
        self.back_btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 60))
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_Back_to_Customer_Screen)

    def go_Back_to_Customer_Screen(self):
        self.st_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)  # +++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не предоставили воспроизводимый пример и это не хорошо. Я взял некоторые модули **.ui** [по ссылки, которую вы указали в предыдущем вашем вопросе](https://github.com/Masik84/My_new_Prog).

Обратите внимание

- я не нашел объект `soldto_btn`, поэтому заменил его на объект `SoldTos`.
- я поменял логику вашего приложения, потому что она становится не читаемая. Теперь у вам есть класс `MainWindow`, в котором дополняются все ваши окна в `QStackedWidget` и  в дальнейшем вам надо будет только переключаться на нужное вам окно.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication

#           -->v
#from Customer_screen import CustomerScreen
from Customer_Screen import CustomerScreen                                # !!! +++
from Soldto_screen import SoldtoScreen                                    # !!! +++


class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):                                           # +++ parent
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
#        loadUi('screens/welcomescreen.ui', self)
        loadUi('welcomescreen.ui', self)
        
        self.parent = parent                                              # +++

        self.cust_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_to_CustomerData)

    def go_to_CustomerData(self):
#        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)
        self.parent.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1)                     # +++ 


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):                                 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        
        self.welcomeScreen = WelcomeScreen(self)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.welcomeScreen)

        self.customerScreen = CustomerScreen(self)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.customerScreen)
        
        self.soldtoScreen = SoldtoScreen(self)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.soldtoScreen)

        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.vlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))
    app.setApplicationDisplayName('Bonus Program')
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 475)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Customer_Screen.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class CustomerScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CustomerScreen, self).__init__()
#        loadUi("screens/customerscreen.ui", self)
        loadUi("customerscreen.ui", self)

        self.parent = parent                                               # +++

        self.back_btn.setIcon(QIcon('Icons/Back.png'))
        self.back_btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 60))
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_Back_to_WelcomeScreen)
        
# ??? ----------> vvvvvvvvvv  <---- ???
# ???        self.soldto_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_to_Soldto_list)
        self.SoldTos.clicked.connect(self.go_to_Soldto_list)                # +++ 

    def go_Back_to_WelcomeScreen(self):
#        self.widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.parent.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)                       # +++ 0

    def go_to_Soldto_list(self):
        self.parent.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(2)                       # +++ 2
```

**Soldto_screen.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SoldtoScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):                               # +++ parent
        super(SoldtoScreen, self).__init__()
#        loadUi("screens/soldtoscreen.ui", self)
        loadUi("soldtoscreen.ui", self)

        self.parent = parent                                  # +++

        self.back_btn.setIcon(QIcon('Icons/Back.png'))
        self.back_btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 60))
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_Back_to_Customer_Screen)

    def go_Back_to_Customer_Screen(self):
#        self.st_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)                     
        self.parent.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)          # +++
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое! Осталось несколько вопросов. 1. я использую VS Code. IDE подчеркивает строку и предлагает заменить на parent_process
'''
        self.parent = parent
'''

Comment: @s-nick Еще выдает ошибку и не работает :(
(https://github.com/Masik84/My_new_Prog/blob/master/error.PNG)

я обновила проект на GitHub, основной файл называется Main_new.py (ссылка  https://github.com/Masik84/My_new_Prog)

еще вопрос. Я правильно понимаю, что для каждого следующего окна нужно будет присваивать свой индекс. Т.е. Soldto_screen в файле Customer имеет индекс 2. Значит следующее прикрепленное к нему окно будет уже 3 и 4, а окна, которые будут дальше открываться из Welcome_screen тоже должны продолжать индексы?

Comment: @Masik в рамках этого вопроса я для вас сделал все что мог. Чтобы убедиться что мой пример работает - скопируйте его и запустите. Я не использую VS Code и не знаю для чего он вам это предлагает. Да, вы правильно поняли, при добавлении нового окна вы в классе MainWindow добавляете его и мысленно запоминаете его индекс в QStackedWidget, чтобы откуда угодно и когда угодно перейти на это окно. Удачи вам.

Comment: Спасибо большое еще раз!! Все получилось! У меня еще вопрос возник. Я правильно понимаю, если я хочу перейти из третьего окна во второе (или из четвертого во второе) в функции с Back мне нужно также указывать индекс окна, который был присвоен ранее

Comment: @Masik да, вы правильно понимаете.